# Map to List by function

Tags: dart

I'm not so familiar with the dart collection library, so I maybe need an easy help.

I have a `Map<K,V>` and `T Function(k, v)`, which produces a T element out of one Map entry. Now I want a `List<T>`. Of course the easy approach does work:

```
List<T> list = [];
map.foreach((k,v) => list.add(myfunc(k,v)));
return list;
```

But I think there should be a more compact version? I found something like `map.values.map((V) => T(V));` but I would strongly prefer to have the key available in my function. Is there a cool short writing for this?

(BTW, my map actually is a `Map<String, Map<String, List<MyType>>>`, and the key value would be in the first MyType down the tree. And I feel that restoring the key with something like `v.first.values.first[0].getSomething` would be more expensive than the upper solution?!)

Answer (score 0):

if you need both key and value try something like

```
 Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> mapOfMaps= new Map();
 //You can use both the key and the value
 mapOfMaps.keys.map((k) => myfunc(k,mapOfMaps[k]));
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
var list = map.keys.map((k) => myfunc(k, map[k])).toList();
```